# PHP date function not working at certain condition

Tags: php

I find a problem related to the date function in php

i want to convert a date '04-08-2016'(mm-dd-yyyy) into a different format '2016-04-08'(yyyy-mm-dd). But it produces the result as '2016-08-04'(yyyy-dd-mm) instead of '2016-04-08'(yyyy-mm-dd).

my code is

```
     $date = '04-08-2016';
     echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
```

If i place '/' in place of '-' then it is working fine.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Whithout your code, it is hard to see why, you know...

Comment: I am just converting into mysql format date(yyyy-mm-dd). For your reference you can take a variable
 $date = '04-08-2016'';echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));

Comment: show your code, don't describe what you do. If it does not have the expected result, you're doing something wrong...

Comment: `strtotime()` works exactly as described [in the PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).... how do you suppose PHP recognises the difference between `dd-mm-yyyy` and `mm-dd-yyyy` for a date like 04-08-2016? Is it the 4th of August, or the 8th of April? How do you recognise the difference? That page in the PHP documents will explain what PHP does, and how it recognises that format

Comment: And if you used DateTime objects, PHP provides a helpful `createFromformat()` method that allows you to tell PHP what format is being used for a date, eliminating any ambiguity or guessing

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: Then how php recognize mm/dd/yyy or dd/mm/yyyy format?

Comment: With your code, now we can see the problems comes from the method "strtotime", which doesn't "guess" your format, as Mark Baker described well...

Comment: @Baker what is wrong in strtotime($date) ?

Comment: @AzharAhmad - read the page that I linked and it will tell you how PHP differentiates between dd-mm-yyyy and mm-dd-yyyy using the separator `"/"` or `"-"`.... there is nothing wrong with strtotime(), just with your lack of knowledge, and that lack willl be eliminated if you read the PHP docs link

Comment: The problem is the dash `-` is for european dates while the slash `/` is for american dates. You don't seem to be making that distinction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DateTime object:

```
$date = '04-08-2016';
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y", $date);
echo $d->format("Y-m-d");
```

The reason you need to do this is date conventions. 
As specified in http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.

Comment: You have forget to provide string in createFromFormat("m-d-Y"). It should be $d = DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y", $date);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$date = '04-08-2016';
$timeArray = strptime($date, '%m-%d-%Y');
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $timeArray['tm_mon']+1, $timeArray['tm_mday'], $timeArray['tm_year']+1900);
echo date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

This allows you to specify the format yourself.